# C# Is there a short cut way to get Left and Right Operators in string

Tags: c#, string, operators

I have a `string` with 2 *operators* in it: `"2 ≤ 8 > 25"`.

is there any way I can get left `≤` operator and right `>` *operator* separately in *array* as below?

```cs
   res[0] = ≤ 
   res[1] = >
```

Please note the *numbers* beside operators (`2`, `8`, `25`) are *not constant*.

Thanks

Comment: If every part of the expression is separated by a space and the expression splitted to the space char is always 5 parts then part[1] and part[3] contains your operators. See [string.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split)

Comment: Do you always have spaces? Do you need to support numbers with decimal points?

Comment: The string split is an array of character to split :            string input = "2 ≤ 8 > 25";
            string[] numbers = input.Split(new char[] {'≤','>',' '},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray();split

Comment: @jdweng Seriously? That code will get you the opposite of what the OP wants...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest querying for *Unicode categories*: all we want are *math symbols* which can be obtained with a simple *Linq*:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  string formula = "2 ≤ 8 > 25";

  // {'≤', '>'}
  char[] res = formula
    .Where(c => char.GetUnicodeCategory(c) == UnicodeCategory.MathSymbol)
    .ToArray();
```

Let's have a look:

```
  Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
    res.Select((value, index) => $"res[{index}] = {value}")));
```

**Outcome:**

```
res[0] = ≤
res[1] = >
```

**Edit:** Same idea (Unicode category) implemented as *regular expression*:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string[] res = Regex
  .Matches(formula, @"\p{Sm}") \\ \p - Unicode Categoty; Sm - Symbol math
  .Cast<Match>()
  .Select(m => m.Value)
  .ToArray();
```

Comment: Nice idea. But you don't cover operators which need more than one `char` like `>=`, if that's possible at all.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: I agree, but since we have `≤` I expect `≥` to be used instead of `>=` (`≠` instead of `!=` etc.). In general case (arbitrary operation set) we ave to use parser.

Answer (score 0):

Provided your input is always in the format you provided then regex should work in this use case.

```
var input = "2 ≤ 8 > 25";
var pattern = new Regex("([^0-9 .]+)");
var result = pattern.Matches(input);
result[0]; // "≤"
result[1]; // ">"
```

**Note**: This will work with and without **spaces** and **decimal places**.

As MikeT mentions below, this code ignores everything that is a number, a space or a decimal place and will return just the operators.

Comment: just to clarify [^] means any character that doesn't match what's in the square brackets, so this reads any character that isn't space or a number and the () means this is the area of interest and the + means one or more occurrences